# Summation of Piecewise Function

Tags: summation

Does the following equation makes any sense at all?

$$
    \frac{1}{|X|\cdot|Y|}\sum\limits_{x \in X}\sum\limits_{y \in Y}\begin{cases}
        1 & \mathrm{if~} x > y\\
        0.5 & \mathrm{if~} x = y\\
        0 & \mathrm{if~} x < y
    \end{cases}
$$

For every comparison of $x$ and $y$, I want to add 1, 0.5 or 0 according to the case statements, and then multiply by the left part of the equation. Is it correct the way it is written? Is there any more beautiful way of designing that equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me. I don't know what you mean by something more beautiful, but you could use the sign function.
$$\frac{1}{|X|\cdot |Y|} \sum_{\substack{x\in X \\ y \in Y}} \frac{1+\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)}{2} $$

Comment: Thanks for your response. By "beautiful" I meant something more didactic, such as splitting into two equations ($f(x)$ for the case statement and another equation for the summation). But what you provided is nice. I am more relieved to know that I didn't mess the equation by designing it the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{|X|\cdot|Y|}\left(|\{(x,y):x \in X,y\in Y:x>y\}|+\frac12|\{(x,y):x \in X,y\in Y:x=y\}|\right).$$

---

Alternatively,
$$\frac1{|X|\cdot|Y|}\left(\sum_{\substack{x\in X \\ y \in Y}}(x>y)+\frac12\sum_{\substack{x\in X \\ y \in Y}}(x=y)\right)$$

Comment: I think that this is a bit less readable than the original equation or than the one posted by Farnight. Nevertheless, thanks for your response.

Comment: That's right, the $|\{\cdot\}|$ notation is not ideal. A $\#$ could be used as well. Anyway, this form uses pure counting, whereas the $\text{sgn}$ approach hides this fact.

Comment: I agree with you. The ideal solution would be to show every component in a more didactic way. For instance, I had to search for $sgn()$ to know what it meant. Your second equation seems a lot better, despite having two sum iterations. Thanks.